# I am getting an error in Dev C++ saying ( invalid operands of types `const double' and `<unknown type>' to binary `operator<<' )

Tags: types, double, constants, dev-c++

Here is where the start of my code is . AT the very bottom of the code, I will have the error spot in detail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare variables

int usedWater = 0;
int prevReading = 0;
int currReading = 0;
const double WATER_RATE = .007;
const double MIN_CHARGES = 16.67;
double totalCharges = 0.0;

cout <<"enter the current reading: ";
cin >> currReading;
cout <<"enter the previous reading: ";
cin >> prevReading;



usedWater = currReading - prevReading;

totalCharges = usedWater * WATER_RATE;

if(totalCharges < MIN_CHARGES)
{

totalCharges = MIN_CHARGES << endl;
cout << "total charges: "  << MIN_CHARGES;   

}
else
{
cout << "Total Charges : " << totalCharges;

} 

cout << "total Charges : " << totalCharges;
cout << "Used Water : " << usedWater;

system ("pause");

 return 0;
}
```

Line 36 is where I am getting the error.  this: (totalCharges = MIN_CHARGES << endl;)
I see no typos at all. Or maybe some wrong word.

Comment: The `<< endl` hanging off the end didn't trigger any alarm bells?

Comment: is that causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
totalCharges = MIN_CHARGES << endl;
```

Not sure exactly what you're trying to acheive with that but I suspect it would be better as:

```
totalCharges = MIN_CHARGES;
```

What your current line is trying to do is set `totalCharges` to the value of `MIN_CHARGES` left-shifted by `endl` bits. That probably wouldn't end well even if the compiler allowed it :-)

---

And, as an aside, you can probably replace a large chunk of that code with the single line:

```
totalCharges = std::min (MIN_CHARGES, usedWater * WATER_RATE);
```

You probably also want to put newlines at the ends of most of those `cout <<` statements so that your output isn't bunched up on one single line.

And the right way to do that is generally with `'\n'` rather than `std::endl` since the latter forces flushing which may lead to degraded performance (though probably not noticeable in this specific case).

Comment: Taking the endl off worked by I dont understand why. Oh well. It works now.

Comment: @RickTheSlick, as to why, see my paragraph starting "What your current line ...".

Comment: @RickTheSlick: What ***did*** you expect `totalCharges = MIN_CHARGES << endl;` to do? I assumed this was unintentional!

Answer (score 1):

`<< endl` does not belong in this assignment:

```
totalCharges = MIN_CHARGES;
```

[`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a stream manipulator for adding a newline and flushing the stream. `MIN_CHARGES` is a `double` `const` value and so such a bitwise left shift operation makes zero sense.

You probably meant:

```
if (totalCharges < MIN_CHARGES)
{
    totalCharges = MIN_CHARGES;
}

cout << "Total Charges : " << totalCharges;
```